# TomEE Plume 7 - JSF 2.2 navigation rules and redirects don't work - primefaces 6.1 + omnifaces 2.6.4

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, tomee-7

I have the following jsf login page:

```
<h:form id="frmAdmLogin" styleClass="form-horizontal">
    <div class="ui-layout-center" style="margin-left: 15px;">
        <p:messages id="messagesLogin" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
        <h:panelGrid cellpadding="5">
            <p:inputText id="txtUsuario" required="true" value="#{loginDataManager.usuario}" />
            <p:password id="pssClave" required="true" value="#{loginDataManager.password}" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="lstSucursales" required="true" value="# {loginDataManager.idSucursal}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{loginController.listadoCatalogos()}" var="sucursal" itemLabel="#{sucursal.nomCatalogo}" itemValue="#{sucursal.id}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Ingresar" action="#{loginController.login()}"  />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </div>
    <div id="barras">
        <ui:include src="/templates/main/barras.xhtml" />
    </div>
</h:form>
```

After user logs in the application, it should redirect to the main page. But It doesn't work.

For navigate I use the following navigation rules:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/login/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-action>#{loginController.login()}</from-action>
   <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/login/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
   <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-action>#{loginController.login()}</from-action>
   <from-outcome>exito</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/login/main.xhtml</to-view-id>
   <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>
```

I have a CDI bean which has the login method:

```
public String login() {
        validarUsuario();
        try {
            obtenerMenu(sessionDataManagerBase.getUserDto());
            return "exito";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
            MessagesController.addError(null, "Error al consultar las opciones de menú para el usuario");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
            return "login";
        }
    }
```

Tomee starts with no errors, and when I click the login button nothing happens: no navigation, no errors in the browser and no errors in Tomee log.

There's something I'm missing in my configuration.
Thanks.

Comment: So it works if you don't use PrimeFaces? Does it work on Tomee-6? Does it work when not using OmniFaces? Is the method called at all?

Comment: @Kukeltje I did it, It doesn't work without using PrimeFaces neither OmiFaces. I tried testing on apache-tomee-1.7.4-plume but It gave me an error because my application is on java 8 and It supports java 6. And the method is called when I click the button but there is no navigation.

Comment: So you can create an example without OmniFaces and PrimeFaces? Please do so and remove all references to them. Adding a plain jsf tag (not jsf-2-2 sice it all does  not seem about a jsf-2.2 specific feature) would help addressing more people